# C# 6, expression bodied function compile error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I was writing the below code in my class, within VS 2015, with Dot Net framework 4.6.1.

```
public int NewWaySum(int a, int b) => return a + b;
```

But it threw a compile error. This is my class:

```
public class MyClass {
    public int NewWaySum(int a, int b) => return a + b;
}
```

According to Msdn, it is compatible with C# 6.0 expression bodied function, and should compile.

I have not used expression bodied function so far.

The error is "invalid token 'return', in class, struct, or interface member declaration.

What is the mistake. The same compile error happens in VS 2017 Community edition

Comment: If I got an "invalid token return" message, just for fun (without thinking), would try remove the 'return' to see what then it says, there are chances to got new information. (this case it is end of story)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In **expression** bodied methods, you don't need a `return`. Because you only state an *expression*, and the value of this expression is what is returned:

```
public int NewWaySum(int a, int b) => a + b;
```

Comment: Thanks guys, now I got the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The expression body mustn't contain `return`. So

```
public int NewWaySum(int a, int b) => a + b;
```

will work